# mysql select where -- repeats every nth day from the start date - between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, time

Looks so simple, but it's actually so hard, at least for me.

**What i have:**
mysql scheme similar to :

```
start_date | end_date | interval
--------------------------------
2016-05-01 00:00:00 | 2016-05-26 00:00:00 | 3
```

**What i want to achieve as results:**
Adding something that actually makes this hard.
I want to get these results depending on the current date. So let's say today is 2016-05-05. The results that i want are as follows:

```
*2016-05-01* <- past date so no match
*2016-05-04* <- past date so no match
**2016-05-07**
**2016-05-10**
**2016-05-13**
etc...
```

I don't want temp tables if possible.

Modulus doesn't work for me, at least for all the different ways i've tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, issues of data display are best handled in application level code, but just for fun...

Note that I'm use a table of integers, but you can use `SELECT 1 i UNION SELECT 2 UNION ... etc` instead if you like...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(start_date DATE,end_date DATE,date_interval INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2016-05-01','2016-05-26',3);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+------------+---------------+
| start_date | end_date   | date_interval |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 2016-05-01 | 2016-05-26 |             3 |
+------------+------------+---------------+

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+   

SELECT start_date + INTERVAL i*date_interval DAY dt 
  FROM my_table
     , ints 
 WHERE start_date + INTERVAL i*date_interval DAY <= end_date;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2016-05-01 |
| 2016-05-04 |
| 2016-05-07 |
| 2016-05-10 |
| 2016-05-13 |
| 2016-05-16 |
| 2016-05-19 |
| 2016-05-22 |
| 2016-05-25 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, i just added the thing that actually made me ask for help. If you could address that too i'll be so grateful!

Comment: Perhaps you can figure that bit out for yourself ;-)